# Cancel pending transaction with Nonce 0

Tags: metamask

When I wanted to deploy a contract via Remix and Metamask, the transaction fees was too high for me ($500), so I reduced the Gas and reduced fees to $170

Since yesterday the transaction has been hanging, and I assume that it will remain it eternally. I read that to replace or cancel a transaction, another transaction must be made with the same number of Nonce.

The problem is that on Ethscan when I see the news of my transaction the number of Nonce is 0.

I wanted to send me money to me even to release the tail but I cannot set the number of Nonce to 0, so now another transaction has been added to the tail and is blocked.

How to cancel a transaction with 0 Nonce?

Comment: What wallet were you using? I think MyEthereumWallet has advanced setting where you can override the nonce.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction has a nonce of 0, it means that it is the first transaction from the account. In this case, you can replace or cancel the transaction by sending a new transaction with the same nonce and a higher gas price. This new transaction will replace the pending transaction and be included in the blockchain.

To do this, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new transaction with the same nonce as the pending transaction and a higher gas price.
2. Sign the new transaction with the same account as the pending transaction.
3. Broadcast the new transaction to the network using your wallet or tool of choice.

When you send the new transaction, the node will recognize that there is an existing transaction with the same nonce, and will replace the pending transaction with the new one.

Keep in mind that if the original transaction was stuck due to insufficient gas, you will need to send the new transaction with a higher gas price to ensure it gets included in the blockchain. Additionally, cancelling or replacing a transaction may not always be successful, especially if the original transaction has already been broadcast to many nodes on the network. In some cases, you may need to wait for the transaction to be dropped from the network, which can take several days.